# Fullcalendar shows the events with one day less

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I am adding this event to my angular app Fullcalendar:

```
{
  end: "2019-12-20T00:00:00+00:00",
  start: "2019-12-18T00:00:00+00:00"
}
```

The event should start on day 18 and until day 19, but it really goes from day 17 to 19.

[image]

What could be wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your local timezone?

Comment: May be time 00:00 is still day before ? So when you change time to some positive it will work ?

Comment: As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object, end dates are **exclusive**. This means that your event will be treated as actually ending on `2019-12-19T23:59:59`. Which is why it doesn't show up on the 20th - because it doesn't actually occupy any time on the 20th, according to the way fullCalendar interprets the end date.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your answer. I understand that. The problem here is regarding the initial date shown a day before.

Comment: @Eldar my local timezone: EST -0500

Comment: @Mises change time to some positive does not work, but -05:00 work, Why is this happening?

Comment: @J_J Don't know exactly may be it is time zone.

Comment: @J_J you should check this [document](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeZone).